# Why am I getting a / in my regex output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My untouched HTML looks like this:

```
<body class="home bc-hide-1bc-hide-2">
```

My JS looks like this:

```
var c = $("body").attr("class").replace(/(bc-hide-\d)/,/$& /);
$("body").attr("class", c);
```

The goal is to get my HTML to look like this (note the space between bc-hide-1 and bc-hide-2):

```
<body class="home bc-hide-1 bc-hide-2">
```

Using the JS above, my output actually ends up with a / in front of each instance of bc-hide-# (seen below):

```
<body class="home /bc-hide-1 /bc-hide-2">
```

I haven't had to do too much with regex and I have been poking around the documentation but I am just not finding what I need to stop that / from outputting. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Using `.attr()` to set the "className" property is not a good idea: use `.prop("className", xxx)` instead.

Comment: Why not fix the code that generates the classes like that? Or is this static content?

Comment: Evan, this is more of a temporary fix to a larger problem that was created previously. The best solution would be to fix the code and that is the long term goal for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the actual question:

> Why am I getting a / in my regex output?

Because you have two slashes in the replacement: `/$& /`.

The replacement should be a string, not a regular expression, and `/$& /.toString()` (the string representation of the expression) is `"/$& /"`.

Just use `'$& '`.

---

But I agree with Evan, you should fix the code that generates the HTML.

Comment: The plan is to fix this properly (by fixing the code generating the classes), unfortunately it's not a quick fix. So I am using this as the quick fix so I can spend the time addressing the real issue. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var c = $("body").attr("class").replace(/(bc-hide-\d)/,'$& ');
```

The replacement is a string, not a regex.  JS turned the regex you passed in into a string, including the slashes.